# How to print const GLubyte* using std::format c++20?

Tags: c++, c++20, iostream

I want to print the OpenGL version using the API const GLubyte *glGetString(GLenum name) using std::format().
Trying the below code gives an error:

```
std::cout << std::format("OpenGL Version: {}\n", glGetString(GL_VERSION));
```

It can be easily printed using iostream with:

```
std::cout << "OpenGL Version: " << glGetString(GL_VERSION);
```

**Tell the best way to print const GLubyte* using the c++20 feature std::format() which is faster than iostream?** I am using Visual Studio 2019.

Answer (score 3):

`GLubyte` is commonly implemented as a `typedef` of `unsigned char`, so the return type of `glGetString(GL_VERSION)` is `const unsigned char*`.

`std::format` does not have a specialization of `std::formatter` for `const unsigned char*`, instead, you can use `reinterpret_cast` to convert it to `const char*` for output

```
std::cout << std::format(
  "OpenGL Version: {}\n", 
  reinterpret_cast<const char*>(glGetString(GL_VERSION)));
```

Comment: Isn't casting for const unsigned char* a limitation for std::format? Every new feature should incorporate existing features also, why did they make it like this? Any comments on this?

Comment: I have no comment on this since I am not an expert on standard I/O. The overload of `operator<<` for `const unsigned char*` doesn't make sense to me since it just simply casts the pointer to `const char*`, I don't see why they need to exist and I never use it.